# twocolumn article class - right side blank

Tags: two-column

I have set up a twocolumn article document that works fine. However, I need to leave all right columns totally blank, so the texts are only displayed on the left side of the twocolumn layout.

The packages parallel, parcolumns, paracol, and parrun do not work as required or demand some major editing of specifications. Is there an easier solution?

[image]

Comment: Use only one column and leave a *big* right margin?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/parallel could help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options. Most easy is to set the right margin to a large length:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=.45\paperwidth]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument{}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! Unfortunately, the proposed solution does not work as required; since there is no possibility to use the figure* or table* command, and the header line on the right side is not shown.

Comment: @msg Then describe what you are trying to do more exactly. Why in the world should the right column be empty, but have a line in the heading? Make a minimal working example.

Comment: @msg this is however the right solution (you can make figures and tables wider (and even have wide mid-column `h` floats) also you can make the headline full width

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You made my day! :-))

Comment: Excuse me, I did not meant to be offensive. Integrating `right=.45\paperwidth` works if minipages are used for titles that should span over both columns. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a more easy way, using `\documentclass[]{revtex4-1}` with option `galley`. It will make your article only on the left side, so the right side is free to write corrections (@Keks Dose: that's the reason, when printing you have the right side to insert corrections, it is really handy :) ).

As an example:

```
 \documentclass[aip,apl,reprint,floatfix, galley]{revtex4-1}
    %Option galley makes the job

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color,soul}
    \usepackage[hang, centerlast, nooneline, FIGTOPCAP]{subfigure}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\author{M. Rossi}
\affiliation{* University, Institute, Postal Code - City, State}
\author{J. Smith}
\affiliation{* University, Institute 2, PC - City, State}

\title{\textbf{Two column - right side blank}}

\begin{abstract}
        \centering
        \noindent
        Abstract text here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
% General intro
\blindtext
~

\begin{center}
    \begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
         & $x$ & Thickness & $T_{comp}$ \\
    \hline 
    sample 1 & 0.7 & 50.5 & 259 \\ 
    \hline 
    sample 2 & 0.64 & 58 & 79 \\ 
    \hline 
    sample 3 & 0.57 & 53 & 150 \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Parameters of random samples (see Fig.~\ref{Fig.4}).}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\bibliography{refarticle}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome. Thank you for your answer, but why use `revtex4-1` which is obsolete and replaced by `revtex4-2`?

Comment: Hello! Yes, you are perfectly right. But I just took an old file that I had on my laptop, I guess the option is still working on the new version.

Comment: I have tried and it only works with 4-2.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the following code is even easier and presents a better final layout, since it doesn't affect the document where it is not wanted (page number remains at the center of page, other texts obeys the original page layout, etc).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{paracol} %... creates empty column



\begin{document}
    \title{Easier and better way to set two columns environment and leave one blank}
    \author{Joaquim}
    \maketitle

\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn[0]
%--> Obs.:
%... 0: empty column to the right
%... 1: empty column to the left

\blinddocument{} %... dummy text to fill the page

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]